# Making minefields with potash

Tags: warfare, chemistry, explosions

Many modern explosives would have changed the history of sieges and raids.

A modern phoenix bomb (american claymore) can injure and entire shieldwall of soldiers.

A field of mines and phoenixes and various such bombs could have protected villages and castles or garrisons for longer.

I imagine not automatic mine fields activated by trip wires cause they can potentially kill wildlife, traders or even just stupid children.

But instead roman like drainage metal tubes with inside them wires. The tubes run underground connecting the bombs outside the castle to levers inside.

Such that the bombs can be triggered only by manual imput from artificiers and never be triggered by innocent ignorants.

The question is, can potash be used to recreate modern mines and similar defense explosives?

Or maybe the bombs can be set ON by trained archers who memorised the location of those mines and use fire arrows.

Comment: [Gunpowder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gunpowder) is actually pretty easy to manufacture with pre-industrial technology. If you know how. And if you have access to natural deposits of saltpeter and sulfur.

Comment: If I'm reading your post correctly, there's already a name for such devices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fougasse_(weapon) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_fougasse

Comment: While a mine or fougasse does indeed produce casualties, that's not it's primary purpose. The primary purpose of a mine(field) in force-on-force fighting is to disrupt, block, or channel an entire enemy formation -- to throw them off their plan. For example, if that formation, stuck behind an apparent minefield, arrives minutes too late to be decisive, their side might lose the battle. A besieging force is not likely to be too worried about a minor schedule delay, since a siege might last weeks or months.

Answer (score 6):

Just because potash is a fertilizer like saltpeter, it doesn't mean you can make explosive with it.

Potash is made by $K_2CO_3$, while saltpeter by $NaNO_3$. Generally speaking the N atom is more than happy to get rid of its bound with O, releasing it, while C is way more possessive.

For an explosion to happen you want to have available oxidizer to react and produce heat and gas, that's why you need to have oxygen. Potash won't do that.

Comment: I took two semesters of chemistry and it all seemed so theoretical. I wish they'd taught me from the perspective of "Will this make a good explosive?"

Comment: I remember a chemistry teacher bringing that topic up, then telling us that he refused to tell us what makes good explosives because he was no fun and because he didn't trust us.  He was correct about not being fun.  I think that joke was the only one he had.

Answer (score 0):

With Potash, no... wrong chemical.

You can do the exact same thing with Saltpeter, sulphur and charcoal though. Plain old Gunpowder.

The problem with using gunpowder in an emplaced mine is that it is not at all weatherproof. One good rainstorm and gunpowder is ruined.

Making the sort of explosives that make landmines, trigger traps, etc. practical requires quite a bit fancier chemistry, or some *very* fancy waterproofing and activating mechanisms. This is why such devices did not really become common until WW2

Answer (score 0):

### Sort of.  Use *calcinated* potash.

Potassium carbonate is mildly basic.  Slaked lime (calcium hydroxide) is a strong base, but limited in its solubility.  Mix the two and you now have calcium carbonate (the lime years to return to being limestone) plus potassium hydroxide, calcinated potash, caustic potash, lye, concentrated drain cleaner, whatever you would like to call it.

Mix a little of that in water and seal it in a small pot, and you now have a missile that a very light catapult can send into the enemy formation.  It won't do much physical damage, but as soldiers are blinded by the splattered lye as carafes crash down on their comrades' heads, their morale may be ... impacted.

Don't forget your regular catapult ammo, in case they turn out to be more angry than afraid.